# Why does my Heroku slug size doubled in size after upgrading Rails and Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I recently upgraded my Rails app from running on Rails 4.2.2 and Ruby 2.3.7 to use Rails 5.2.2 and Ruby 2.6.5. Everything seems to work great in development so I'm trying to deploy it to a review app on Heroku, but the compressed slug size turned out to be `522.1M`, which is over the 500M allowed.

Before the upgrade, we were only at `246.4M`. I didn't add any new gems with the upgrade, just updated some gems to work with the newer version of Rails. All assets are also the same as before.

EDIT: I wrote that I was trying to deploy to staging before, but I realized that wasn't the case. We're trying to create a new review app on that branch to test it out first before merging it. Since this is a brand new review app, I don't think caching is an issue...right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It was the `wkhtmltopdf_binary_gem` gem. I guess I accidentally upgraded its version to `0.12.5`, which quadrupled in size and not really fit to use with heroku. Here's the issue link: https://github.com/zakird/wkhtmltopdf_binary_gem/issues/55. I downgraded it to 0.12.4 and everything works now.

Comment: does the fillable form pdf is working with 0.12.4. Its not working for me as the fields are not editable

Comment: @Jaswinder Everything works fine for my purposes. However, if you're having issues with 0.12.4, have you tried switching to https://github.com/rposborne/wkhtmltopdf-heroku instead? It's on my TODO list and I'll switch at a later time but it seems like a better gem to use with Heroku.